# htaccess Rewrite for clean URLs 2 get variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Url rewriting doesn't seem to work.
I want to rewrite `http://www.domain.com/files.php?key=file&id=10` to `file/10`

So this is the code I wrote in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteRule ^(.*?) files.php?key=$1&id=$2
```

Doesn't seem to work. Anyone having a idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two groups to use $2. Try

```
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/? files.php?key=$1&id=$2
```

`[^/]+` Means one or more symbols each of them isn't slash

Comment: it's working fine but problem with my /dir/ Eg. `css/style.css` it's not working, how to fix it?

Comment: @SalmaAkter, Fixed to allow only numbers in second group

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ files.php?key=$1&id=$2
```